Why citing is only show the first reference
Why the citation is only taking the first reference
I am using Overleaf based on this template
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% file template.tex %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% This is a general template file for the LaTeX package SVJour3
% for Springer journals.          Springer Heidelberg 2010/09/16
%
% Copy it to a new file with a new name and use it as the basis
% for your article. Delete % signs as needed.
%
% This template includes a few options for different layouts and
% content for various journals. Please consult a previous issue of
% your journal as needed.
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% First comes an example EPS file -- just ignore it and
% proceed on the \documentclass line
% your LaTeX will extract the file if required
\begin{filecontents*}{example.eps}
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
%%BoundingBox: 19 19 221 221
%%CreationDate: Mon Sep 29 1997
%%Creator: programmed by hand (JK)
%%EndComments
gsave
newpath
  20 20 moveto
  20 220 lineto
  220 220 lineto
  220 20 lineto
closepath
2 setlinewidth
gsave
  .4 setgray fill
grestore
stroke
grestore
\end{filecontents*}
%
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
%
%\documentclass{svjour3}                     % onecolumn (standard format)
%\documentclass[smallcondensed]{svjour3}     % onecolumn (ditto)
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}       % onecolumn (second format)
%\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}          % twocolumn
%
\smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof
%
\usepackage{graphicx}
%
% \usepackage{mathptmx}      % use Times fonts if available on your TeX system
%
% insert here the call for the packages your document requires
%\usepackage{latexsym}
% etc.
%
% please place your own definitions here and don't use \def but
% \newcommand{}{}
%
% Insert the name of "your journal" with
% \journalname{myjournal}
%
\begin{document}

\title{Insert your title here%\thanks{Grants or other notes
%about the article that should go on the front page should be
%placed here. General acknowledgments should be placed at the end of the article.}
}
\subtitle{Do you have a subtitle?\\ If so, write it here}

%\titlerunning{Short form of title}        % if too long for running head

\author{First Author         \and
        Second Author %etc.
}

%\authorrunning{Short form of author list} % if too long for running head

\institute{F. Author \at
              first address \\
              Tel.: +123-45-678910\\
              Fax: +123-45-678910\\
              \email{fauthor@example.com}           %  \\
%             \emph{Present address:} of F. Author  %  if needed
           \and
           S. Author \at
              second address
}

\date{Received: date / Accepted: date}
% The correct dates will be entered by the editor


\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Insert your abstract here. Include keywords, PACS and mathematical
subject classification numbers as needed.
\keywords{First keyword \and Second keyword \and More}
% \PACS{PACS code1 \and PACS code2 \and more}
\subclass{MSC code1 \and MSC code2 \and more}
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
\label{intro}
Your text comes here. Separate text sections with
\section{Section title}
\label{sec:1}
Text with citations \cite{RefB, RefJ}.
\subsection{Subsection title}
\label{sec:2}
as required. Don't forget to give each section
and subsection a unique label (see Sect.~\ref{sec:1}).
\paragraph{Paragraph headings} Use paragraph headings as needed.
\begin{equation}
a^2+b^2=c^2
\end{equation}

% For one-column wide figures use
\begin{figure}
% Use the relevant command to insert your figure file.
% For example, with the graphicx package use
  \includegraphics{example.eps}
% figure caption is below the figure
\caption{Please write your figure caption here}
\label{fig:1}       % Give a unique label
\end{figure}
%
% For two-column wide figures use
\begin{figure*}
% Use the relevant command to insert your figure file.
% For example, with the graphicx package use
  \includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth]{example.eps}
% figure caption is below the figure
\caption{Please write your figure caption here}
\label{fig:2}       % Give a unique label
\end{figure*}
%
% For tables use
\begin{table}
% table caption is above the table
\caption{Please write your table caption here}
\label{tab:1}       % Give a unique label
% For LaTeX tables use
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
first & second & third  \\
\noalign{\smallskip}\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
number & number & number \\
number & number & number \\
\noalign{\smallskip}\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


%\begin{acknowledgements}
%If you'd like to thank anyone, place your comments here
%and remove the percent signs.
%\end{acknowledgements}


% Authors must disclose all relationships or interests that 
% could have direct or potential influence or impart bias on 
% the work: 
%
% \section*{Conflict of interest}
%
% The authors declare that they have no conflict of interest.


% BibTeX users please use one of
%\bibliographystyle{spbasic}      % basic style, author-year citations
%\bibliographystyle{spmpsci}      % mathematics and physical sciences
%\bibliographystyle{spphys}       % APS-like style for physics
%\bibliography{}   % name your BibTeX data base

% Non-BibTeX users please use
\begin{thebibliography}{}
%
% and use \bibitem to create references. Consult the Instructions
% for authors for reference list style.
%
\bibitem{RefJ}
% Format for Journal Reference
Author, Article title, Journal, Volume, page numbers (year)
% Format for books
\bibitem{RefB}
Author, Book title, page numbers. Publisher, place (year)
% etc
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
% end of file template.tex

but the compiled version is only taking the first reference
Here is my output


If you show no code, how on earth are we suppose to help?

The code you show does not reproduce the problem.

@daleif the code now shows the problem

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz the code not shows the problem

To quote the matrix: "There is no code, only screenshots"

Use \cite{RefB,RefJ} (no space):
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}     

\begin{document}

Text with citations \cite{RefB,RefJ}.

\begin{thebibliography}{}
\bibitem{RefJ}
Author, Article title, Journal, Volume, page numbers (year)
\bibitem{RefB}
Author, Book title, page numbers. Publisher, place (year)
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}


